# For an $n$ by $n$ matrix with integer entries and odd determinant, show for some positive $k$ all entries of the matrix $A^k - I$ are even

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, linear-groups

the following is a question from a qualifying exam for abstract algebra:

**If $A$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$ and odd determinant then show for some positive number $k$, all entries of the matrix $A^k - I$ are even.
Hint:  work over the finite field $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$**

My first effort was to try to use the characteristic polynomial somehow, but I unfortunately could not get what I wanted, so I attempted a different approach.

Working over $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$, since det($A$) is odd,  det($A) \equiv 1 \mod2$.

So we can consider $A$ as an element of $GL(n, \mathbb{Z}/(2))$, the general linear group over the finite field $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$.

$GL(n,F_q)$ has order $\displaystyle \Pi_{i=1}^n (q^n - q^{i-1})$, so in our case

$$|GL(n, \mathbb{Z}/(2))| = \Pi_{i=1}^n (2^n - 2^{i-1})$$

The most important part is that $GL(n, \mathbb{Z}/(2))$ has finite order, and for $A \in GL(n, \mathbb{Z}/(2))$, $|A|$ divides $|GL(n, \mathbb{Z}/(2))|$, so $A$ has finite order.

Thus there exists some positive $k$ so that $A^k = I$.

So $A^k - I = 0$ $(\mod 2$), meaning that $A^k -I$ has all even entries.

Any and all feedback on this proof would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof works perfectly well!  It would be slightly quicker, however, to simply take $k = |GL(n,\Bbb Z_2)|$, noting only that this group is finite (there is no need to explicitly state its order).

Comment: Ah yes, very true.  I probably wouldn't bother too much with writing its order on the qualifier itself, I wrote it out here more as a sanity check and practice.  Thank you!

Comment: @SallyK you got it! I think cutting out the extra bits from a proof is particularly useful during qualifying exams or timed environments

Comment: @Omnomnomnom is the boss of trick linear algebra questions.

Comment: @dREaM daw, shucks...